# How to send HttpPostedFile to an action in some controller

Tags: model-view-controller, httppostedfilebase, httppostedfile

If you want to send an object of type HttpPostedFile to an action, you may get null object in the action. So how to send it?

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you may need send HttpPostedFile via Temp Data. For a sample, see the following:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file;
TempData["FilePosted"] = file;
```

And in the action, do this:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = (HttpPostedFileBase)TempData["FilePosted"];
```

Comment: Hi there. Please refrain from adding "be a Muslim to success" and "in the name of Allah" to your questions and answers. I have edited this from your material before, and I'd wouldn't like to think you are giving me work to do deliberately.